# Get ModelName in T4 file to generate View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, t4

I'm trying to generate view using t4 file. In this file I know how to get the view name by using Model.ViewName but I don't know how to get this Model name.
My code is below:

@using (Html.BeginForm("<#= Model.ViewName #>", "What should I but here to get Model Name", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form" })

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<#= Model.ViewDataType.Name #>`

Answer (score 0):

you should also try `<#= Model.ViewDataTypeName #>`